# Is there a unicode currency symbol for DAI?

Tags: dai, makerdao

USD uses the symbol **$**. Ether has **Ξ**. Is there an agreed-upon Unicode currency symbol for DAI?

And in your answer, please don't point me to an image of the symbol. I'm asking specifically if there's a Unicode symbol that I can paste into an MS Word document for example.

Bonus points if you include other popular tokens such as USDT or Wrapped Ether.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DAI - From the [developer docs](https://developer.makerdao.com/dai/1/):

> Dai has adopted the unicode diamond as its symbolic representation:
>
> ◈ 100 dai

USDT - [Official Naming Conventions](https://tether.to/branding/)

> USD₮, EUR₮, JPY₮: crypto USD, EUR & JPY issued by Tether Operations
>   Limited. Similar to bitcoin utilizing the unicode symbol Ƀ, Tether
>   tokens are represented by the unicode symbol ₮ (Tugrik sign).

Answer (score 2):

See the following Reddit post: [貸 dai ◈](https://www.reddit.com/r/MakerDAO/comments/5q98b1/%E8%B2%B8_dai/)

> ⬙ Was the first unicode character I wanted for the dai. Mainly because
>   it looks like a diamond and has the nice little triangle showing which
>   way the price is going ;). However I ended up not liking it for a
>   number of reasons, first of all the unicode symbol looks weirdly
>   lopsided in most fonts for god knows what reason. Secondly in the end
>   I'm not so confident that the dai will be strictly deflationary, and
>   as such it's a bad idea to have it a as a foundational part of the
>   symbolism. And also it's quite tacky to have the symbolism appeal to
>   the greed instinct.
>
> Instead ◈ was suggested...

◈ => ...

- `\u25c8` in UTF-16
- `\xe2\x97\x88` in UTF-8